# Kafka with ElasticsearchSinkConnector - Is it possible to define the data mapping in the connetor?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, mapping, confluent-platform

I use Kafka with the following connector `connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector`
in order to send data to ElasticSearch. This combination already works well.

My problem:
My environment is fully dockered, and I need to set the whole system up multiple times per day. Each time, I need to map the structure of the data for each index on ES before I can send any data from Kafka. Otherwise, ES uses the wrong data types, and I can't work with the data without re-indexing. The dynamic mapping function sadly doesn't work for me good enough. Right now I use a bash script which sets the mappings for the index.

My question:
Is there a way to set/define the mapping already in the connector ? So I don't need to run my bash script ?

Comment: You could scan over the source code and find out, but I think the answer is there is not. The type mappings already should be there if you use schemas in your records